# Spring Boot ModelMapper - no Session

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa, modelmapper

Im trying to code an RestAPI. My Database is filled with data (about 90000 rows for the considered table). I want to select some data (about 500). For performance, I want to do this multithreaded.Without threads everything works but if I use a ThreadpoolExecutor to use threads and after all threads are finished I want to return the list of fetched rows as DTo to the controller, I get the Exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.ghlabs.betpredictorapi.entity.Team#3] - no Session
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]
at com.ghlabs.betpredictorapi.entity.Team$HibernateProxy$Be4OggaP.getAwayTeamMatches(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:na]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor96.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.modelmapper.internal.PropertyInfoImpl$MethodAccessor.getValue(PropertyInfoImpl.java:101) ~[modelmapper-2.3.8.jar:na]
at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.resolveSourceValue(MappingEngineImpl.java:197) ~[modelmapper-2.3.8.jar:na]
at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.propertyMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:171) ~[modelmapper-2.3.8.jar:na]
at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:152) ~[modelmapper-2.3.8.jar:na]
at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:106) ~[modelmapper-2.3.8.jar:na]
at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:72) ~[modelmapper-2.3.8.jar:na]
at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:573) ~[modelmapper-2.3.8.jar:na]
at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:406) ~[modelmapper-2.3.8.jar:na]
at com.ghlabs.betpredictorapi.service.MatchService.convertToMatchDTO(MatchService.java:110) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
at com.ghlabs.betpredictorapi.service.MatchService.findByLeagueAndSeasonRange(MatchService.java:89) ~[classes/:na]
at com.ghlabs.betpredictorapi.controller.CalculationController.calculateMatch(CalculationController.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:807) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

These are the functions Im using (Im calling findByLeagueAndSeasonRange-function):

```
        public List<MatchDTO> findByLeagueAndSeasonRange(Long leagueId, int minSeasonYearEnd, int maxSeasonYearEnd) {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0,50, Sort.by("matchDate").descending());
    Page<Match> page = matchRepository.findByLeagueAndSeasonRange(leagueId, minSeasonYearEnd, maxSeasonYearEnd, pageable);
    List<Match> matches = new ArrayList<>(page.getContent());

    logger.info("---- Total Pages: " + page.getTotalPages());
    logger.info("Page " + 1 + " - Elements: " + page.getNumberOfElements());

    for (int i = 1; i < page.getTotalPages(); i++) {
        int finalI = i;
        Callable<List<Match>> callable = () -> {
            Pageable pageable2 = PageRequest.of(finalI,50);
            Page<Match> p = matchRepository.findByLeagueAndSeasonRange(leagueId, minSeasonYearEnd, maxSeasonYearEnd, pageable2);

            logger.info("Page " + (finalI + 1)+ " - Elements: " + p.getNumberOfElements());
            return p.getContent();
        };
        Future<List<Match>> future = es.submit(callable);
        try {
            List<Match> futureMatches = future.get();
            matches.addAll(futureMatches);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    shutdownAndAwaitTermination(es);
    logger.info(matches.size() + " matches fetched from database.");

    return matches.stream()
            .map(this::convertToMatchDTO)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
    pool.shutdown();
    try {
        if (!pool.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            pool.shutdownNow();
            if (!pool.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                logger.error("Pool did not terminate");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        pool.shutdownNow();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}

private MatchDTO convertToMatchDTO(Match match) {
    modelMapper.getConfiguration()
            .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);
    return modelMapper
            .map(match, MatchDTO.class);
}
```

The considered entity in the exception is the following:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Team implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String teamName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_league", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private League league;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="homeTeam")
    List<Match> homeTeamMatches;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="awayTeam")
    List<Match> awayTeamMatches;

    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
    private Date updatedAt;

    public Team(String teamName, League league) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.league = league;
    }

    @PrePersist
    private void createdAt() {
        this.createdAt = new Date();
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    private void updatedAt() {
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Team team = (Team) o;
        return id.equals(team.id) &&
                teamName.equals(team.teamName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, teamName);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Team{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", teamName='" + teamName + '\'' +
                ", league=" + league +
                ", homeTeamMatches=" + homeTeamMatches +
                ", awayTeamMatches=" + awayTeamMatches +
                ", createdAt=" + createdAt +
                ", updatedAt=" + updatedAt +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And this is the Entity Im getting from the database:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "matches")
public class Match {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Date matchDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_homeTeam", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Team homeTeam;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_awayTeam", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Team awayTeam;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_league", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private League league;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_season", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Season season;

    private int homeTeamFTGoals;
    private int awayTeamFTGoals;
    private int homeTeamHTGoals;
    private int awayTeamHTGoals;
    private boolean homeTeamFTWins;
    private boolean awayTeamFTWins;
    private boolean homeTeamHTWins;
    private boolean awayTeamHTWins;
    private boolean drawFT;
    private boolean drawHT;
    private int homeTeamShots;
    private int awayTeamShots;
    private int homeTeamShotsOnTarget;
    private int awayTeamShotsOnTarget;
    private int homeTeamHitWoodWork;
    private int awayTeamHitWoordWork;
    private int homeTeamCorners;
    private int awayTeamCorners;
    private int homeTeamFoulsCommitted;
    private int awayTeamFouldCommitted;
    private int homeTeamFreekicksConceeded;
    private int awayTeamFreekicksConceeded;
    private int homeTeamOffsides;
    private int awayTeamOffsides;
    private int homeTeamYellowCards;
    private int awayTeamYellowCards;
    private int homeTeamRedCards;
    private int awayTeamRedCards;

    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
    private Date updatedAt;

    public Match(League league, Season season, Date matchDate, Team homeTeam, Team awayTeam, int fthg, int ftag, int hthg, int htag, boolean b, boolean b1, boolean b2, boolean b3, boolean b4, boolean b5, int hs, int as, int hst, int ast, int hhw, int ahw, int hc, int ac, int hf, int af, int hfkc, int afkc, int ho, int ao, int hy, int ay, int hr, int ar) {
        this.league = league;
        this.season = season;
        this.matchDate = matchDate;
        this.homeTeam = homeTeam;
        this.awayTeam = awayTeam;
        this.homeTeamFTGoals = fthg;
        this.awayTeamFTGoals = ftag;
        this.homeTeamHTGoals = hthg;
        this.awayTeamHTGoals = htag;
        this.homeTeamFTWins = b;
        this.awayTeamFTWins = b1;
        this.homeTeamHTWins = b2;
        this.awayTeamHTWins = b3;
        this.drawFT = b4;
        this.drawHT = b5;
        this.homeTeamShots = hs;
        this.awayTeamShots = as;
        this.homeTeamShotsOnTarget = hst;
        this.awayTeamShotsOnTarget = ast;
        this.homeTeamHitWoodWork = hhw;
        this.awayTeamHitWoordWork = ahw;
        this.homeTeamCorners = hc;
        this.awayTeamCorners = ac;
        this.homeTeamFoulsCommitted = hf;
        this.awayTeamFouldCommitted = af;
        this.homeTeamFreekicksConceeded = hfkc;
        this.awayTeamFreekicksConceeded = afkc;
        this.homeTeamOffsides = ho;
        this.awayTeamOffsides = ao;
        this.homeTeamYellowCards = hy;
        this.awayTeamYellowCards = ay;
        this.homeTeamRedCards = hr;
        this.awayTeamRedCards = ar;
    }

    @PrePersist
    private void createdAt() {
        this.createdAt = new Date();
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    private void updatedAt() {
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Match match = (Match) o;
        return id.equals(match.id) &&
                matchDate.equals(match.matchDate) &&
                homeTeam.equals(match.homeTeam) &&
                awayTeam.equals(match.awayTeam) &&
                Objects.equals(league, match.league) &&
                Objects.equals(season, match.season);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, matchDate, homeTeam, awayTeam, league, season);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Match{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", matchDate=" + matchDate +
                ", homeTeam=" + homeTeam +
                ", awayTeam=" + awayTeam +
                ", league=" + league +
                ", season=" + season +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?